# How can i showcustom UI Notification when app is running

Tags: ios, notifications

I want to show custom UI for notification when App is running but.(Like in whats app). How can i do this custom view. I tried do this in **userNotificationCenter** but its only showing default notification.

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
```

I want to show notification like whats app when app is runing. Do you have any idea how to do this?

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
showUIViewController()
}

func showUIViewController() {
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyPage", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactUsDetailViewController") as! ContactUsDetailViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: You need to call completion handler with an empty array in this function. This means you do not want to play any sounds or display the default alert or badges.

Comment: If possible, post your implementation of this function so I can guide you.

Comment: @MahsaYousefi yes i call completion handler in there so it only showing default  notification.I need to show notification like whatsapp running state.

Comment: @MahsaYousefi i added code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after calling `showUIViewController()` call the `completionHandler` with an empty array:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    showUIViewController()
    //1
    completionHandler([])
  }
```

1- This code will prevent the system to show the default iOS notification.

Then, Your piece of code to show custom UI for notifications like whatsapp does not make sense.
You should create a custom view and add/remove it as a subview of `UIWindow` instead of changing its `rootViewController`.

Comment: Great !!!. It works for me . But have small issue i have buttons in this subview but Tap Gesture not working.

Comment: It can because of lots of reasons, make sure that the element you are adding a tap gesture on, is user interaction enabled. You can also take advantage of view debugging using view hierarchy.

Comment: yes i checked user interaction enabled. I add this subview to window in AppDelegate. Is there any problem to add it in AppDelegate.
Because some times when i click out side this subview trigget the tap.

Comment: Telling what your problem is without seeing your code is almost impossible. I hope my answer is helpful to you about showing/hiding default notifications, about the other problem I think you can post another question with appropriate details.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to customize the **notification** when app is in **foreground** , I have used the third party and it's really cool and easy to implement, Check this out

**https://github.com/souzainf3/RNNotificationView**